# how to invalidate toxenv

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, python-packaging, tox, protobuf-python

I have some tox project that processes some protobuf in the install-deps phase and outputs some `*pb.py` codecs (custom script executed as `install_command` option in the config). When I'm updating my workspace (and the protobuf files are updated), i would like to somehow mark the toxenv as invalid - so that it would get recreated **without the need of passing `-r, --recreate` flags** to some later `tox` call. I could add such action the the script that does the env update. Any idea on how to do it?
i'm using some older tox - 3.14

Comment: But *tox* re-installs (and re-builds) the project every time, right? I wonder how come that those `*pb.py` file are not generated as part of the build process of the project, instead of in the *tox* `install_command`.

Comment: extarnal stuff - not produced by tox. thats just an example - you could put any other kind of input files there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out its described quite verbosly in the doc:
https://tox.wiki/en/3.14.6/example/general.html?highlight=recreate#dependency-changes-and-tracking

> Here’s what traits we track at the moment for each steps:
>
> - virtual environment trait is tied to the python path the basepython resolves too (if this config changes, the virtual environment will be recreated),
> - deps sections changes (meaning any string-level change for the entries, note requirement file content changes are not tracked),
> - library dependencies are tracked at extras level (because there’s no Python API to enquire about the actual dependencies in a non-tool specific way, e.g. setuptools has one way, flit something else, and poetry another).

Also from what i looked into tox code, here are the attributes that are checked
https://tox.wiki/en/3.14.6/_modules/tox/venv.html?highlight=matches_with_reason

- `base_resolved_python_sha256`
- `base_resolved_python_path`
- `tox_version`
- `sitepackages`
- `usedevelop`
- `alwayscopy`

Apart from that, the first and most obvious way is to simply remove the `<toxworkdir>` dir on the env update. Other possibility can be to remove/rename the `<toxenvdir>/.tox-config1` file.